# Replace spaces with tabs

Tags: regex, powershell, split

I have some text content and would like to split in more friendly view and later export to CSV format. I want to replace the first couple of spaces with tab. I tried something with regex pattern `\s`, but it split all text.

You may see sample data and my results
[image]

Comment: What are the _first spaces_ you speak of? Please edit your question and add the text you have as formatted TEXT, not as link to an image. Also provide a sample of the desired output.

Comment: For the first consecutive spaces in a line, you can use ```-replace '(?<=^\S+)\s+',"`t"```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$sourceFilePath  = 'c:\infile.txt'
$destFilePath    = 'c:\outfile.txt'

$writeHandle     = [System.IO.File]::OpenWrite( $destFilePath )

foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($sourceFilePath))
{
    $outbuf = [byte[]][char[]](($line -replace '^(.*?) (.*?) (.*?) (.*?) (.*)$', '$1*$2*$3*$4*$5').Replace("*", "`t") + [environment]::NewLine)
    [void]$writeHandle.Write( $outbuf, 0, $outbuf.Length )
}

[void]$writeHandle.Close()
```

Comment: yes this is working for me -replace '^(.*?) (.*?) (.*?) (.*?)', '$1*$2*$3*$4'.Replace("*", "`t") thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
$inputtext = Get-Content 'EQ-Input.txt'
$outputobject = foreach ($Line in $inputtext) {
    $arr = $line -split ' '
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Date = $arr[0]
        Time = $arr[1]
        Code = $arr[2]
        Result = $arr[3..($arr.Length-1)] -join ' '
    }
}
```

Then you can use `$outputobject` for further analysis or you can convert it or save it as CSV.

```
$outputobject | ConvertTo-Csv
$outputobject | Export-Csv -Path 'EQ-Output.csv'
```

Comment: Igor the Result array not parsing well got the first word only

Comment: Instead of joining the results again, use the [<max-substrings>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-6#max-substrings) parameter: `-Split ' ',4`, which will simply put the rest of the array in `$arr[3]`.